# Как решить проблему создания новых потоков java.io?

Tags: java, многопоточность, асинхронность

Во время разработки сетевого приложения, столкнулся с проблемой того, что необходимо создавать новый поток для каждого подключения, чтобы принимать сообщения. Однако когда я задался вопросом "А что если 100/1000/10000/... подключений одновременно?", то начал искать решение, которое позволило бы решить данную проблему на java.io, но так и не нашел на просторах интернета. И так вопрос, какое возможно решение этой проблемы с использованием java.io?
Ниже код для наглядности.

```
// Класс, принимающий подключения
public class AccepterIO extends AbstractAccepter {
    private ServerSocket ServerSocket;
    private LinkedList<ConnectionIO> Connections;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!this.Shutdown) {
                Socket clientSocket = this.ServerSocket.accept();

                ConnectionIO con = new ConnectionIO(clientSocket);

                this.Connections.add(con);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// Класс, описывающий подключение
public class ConnectionIO {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private BufferedWriter out;

    public ConnectionIO(Socket clientsocket) {
        this.socket = clientsocket;

        try {
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientsocket.getInputStream()));
            this.out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientsocket.getOutputStream()));

            // problem here
            this.in.readLine();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно какую проблему ты пытаешься решить этим кодом? 10000 подключений одновременно - это не реально. Искал в интернете и ничего не нашел? Это неправда.

Comment: @RomanC, как обрабатывать каждое подключение не в отдельном потоке. В этом проблема

Comment: Уточни свою проблему, добавь детали код релевантный, как проблему можно воспроизвести.